# How to get data from TikTok and Instagram

Tags: python, database, instagram, analyzer, tiktok

I'm thinking about extracting TikTok data (views, likes, comments and saves) from videos of an account and some audios. On the other hand from Instagram I want to extract the same but for a single account.

Any idea what is the best way to program it without getting banned by some app. Or what kind of webscrapping would be best to do given the terms and conditions of each company.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have used this website myself for twitter data scraping and it worked for me hopefully it will be the solution to your problem.
https://phantombuster.com/phantombuster?category=instagram

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).